# Defined what is meant by a orthogonal projection from an inner product V to a subspace W of V

Tags: linear-algebra

I cant find the answer from the textbook, can anyone help me with this...

I don't know if this could be the answer:
$$p= \frac {a•b}{a•a} a$$

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The definition of an orthogonal projection on a Hilbert space (a complete inner product space) is a self-adjoint, idempotent endomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to project a vector $b$ onto the line of the vector $a$. Let's start from a simple case, and then we will gradually get to  explain your formula.

Suppose $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is the vector you want to project it on the first axis. You can draw a diagram, but you will be convinced that the result is $p=(b_1,0,0)$.

Now, let the vector $a = (1,0,0)$. This is the unit vector along the first axis. note that $a ~ . b = b_1$, the vector $(a~.b)a$  is indeed the vector $p$ we just calculated. Also, since $a ~. a = 1$, the formula that you gave us.

Now, let the vector $a' = 2a = (2,0,0)$. This is another vector along the first axis. Note that $a' ~ . b = (2b_1,0,0)$ is NOT the vector $p$ we just calculated. But, since $a' ~.  a' = 4$, the formula that you gave us does indeed yield the the vector we are looking for.

Intuitively, what is going on is that $a~. b$ gives an amount of how much $b$ leans against $a$. The term $a$ gives the direction you are pointing towards and the term $(a~.~a)^{-1}$ corrects for the length of $a$.